# How to optimize / speedup the performance of one-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, persistence

In the application we have many Sites and Nodes. The entities are :

```
public class Site {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "site")
    @Cache(region = "visionaelCache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @BatchSize(size = 25)
    private Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
}

public class Node {
    @QueryableRelationship(direction = QueryableRelationship.Direction.PARENT)
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_id")
    private Site site;

    ...

    public void addToNodes(Node node) {
       node.setSite(this);
       this.nodes.add(node);
    }
}
```

When we added a node to site using `mySite.addToNodes(myNode)` it takes too much time to complete the operation. Any suggestion on speeding up this operation?

Comment: It happens when you add single node or when you add many ?

Comment: It happens when I add single Node. And the site has already many nodes associated to it.

Comment: wonder what the log says about what is happening when you do that ? ...

Comment: Log says fine. Only problem it takes too much time to complete the operation. @DN1 do you want to see something specific in log?

Comment: I simply tell you where to look for information (aka debugging). It is for you to make sense of what your JPA provider puts at debug level to identify why it takes so long. Connection takes long time to be allocated? SQL invoked is inefficient? something else takes time?